# Intellij error "HTML::Mason components are not configured"

Tags: intellij-idea, mason, perl

I am trying to work with Perl/Mason packages on Intellij. I see red underlines everywhere with an error saying "HTML::Mason components are not configured". What steps do I need to take to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, go to the **Settings** menu, select **Perl5**, select your project, click the "HTML::Mason components" button, and select your source folder.

[image: Component roots]

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the source directory of your components folder where you are going to store your `*.mas`(components) files.
Go to `Settings`, select `Perl5` and then select you component root folder.